# Same Calculation, different result?

Tags: java, math, percentage

My goal is to calculate how many percent `counter` out of `cap` is.
Now I ran over a problem, I can't find the difference between the two formulas below, as far as my mathematical understanding tells me, it's exactly the same calculation. But only the first one works, brackets make no difference.

`int i = counter * 100 / cap; //works`
`int i = counter / cap * 100; //doesn't work`

Has this got something to do with java or is it just me who's made a horrible thinking mistake?

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? For what inputs?

Comment: You could easily find out by debugging the result of `counter / cap`.

Comment: are `counter` and `cap` both `int`? if yes `counter/cap` will get 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that these are just pure, abstract numbers. I assume that `counter` is an `int`... so the second version is evaluated as:

```
int tmp = counter / cap;
int i = tmp * 100;
```

Now we're dealing with *integer arithmetic* here - so if `counter` is in the range [-99, 99] for example, `tmp` will be 0.

Note that even your first version may not work, either - if `counter` is very large, multiplying it by 100 may overflow the bounds of `int`, leading to a negative result. Still, that's probably your best approach if `counter` is expected to be in a more reasonable range.

Even with floating point arithmetic, you still don't get the behaviour of "pure" numbers, of course - there are still limits both in terms of range and precision.

Comment: Yes both counter and cap ar `Int`. So I'd have to use float and it will work?

Comment: @WayneEra: Well that's one option. Or multiply by 100 first. Basically, you need to understand what's going on, then you can decide the most appropriate course of action.

Comment: ok I didn't remember that `int` `float` don't work the same way. So thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the same calculation, since you are handling **integer arithmetics**, which does not have [Multiplicative inverse number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) for all numbers (only 1 has it).

In integer arithmetics, for example, `1/2 == 0`, and not `0.5` - as it is in real numbers arithmetics. This will of course cause later on inconsistency when multiplying.

As already mentioned - the root of this is the fact that integer arithmetics does not behave like real numbers arithmetics, and in particular, the divide operator is not defined as `a/b == a*b^-1`, since `b^-1` is not even defined in integer arithmetics to all numbers but 1.

Answer (score 1):

First case

```
int i = counter * 100 / cap;
```

is evaluated like

```
(counter * 100) / cap;
```

The second case

```
int i = counter / cap * 100;
```

is evluated like this

```
(counter / cap) * 100
```

Hence different results

Comment: I now get what my problem was, but you will agree that it is mathematically the same ;)

Comment: Glad it helped you :) , this is all due to operator precendence https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

In Java, operators * and / have the same precedence, so the expressions are evaluated sequentially. I.e.

1. counter * 100 / cap --> (counter * 100) / cap
2. counter / cap * 100 --> (counter / cap) * 100

So for values e.g. counter = 5, cap = 25 (expecting count and cap to be both int variables), the evaluation is in the first case: 5 * 100 = 500, then 500 / 25 = 20

In the second case, the evaluation is: 5 / 25 = 0 (integer math!), then 0 * 100 = 0.